# setState doesnt persist state outside function scope

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

the listFilesAndDirectories function from the firebase storage API reference is what am using to get the download URL for my images saved in the storage bucket already but using setState to preserve state as url till passed as image uri doesn't work

```
import React, {setState} from 'react';
import {DrawerActions, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Gallery: () => React$Node = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function listFilesAndDirectories(reference, pageToken) {
    return reference.list({pageToken}).then(result => {
      result.items.forEach(ref => {
        // call getDownloadURL on every object reference
        ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          setState({url: url});
          console.log(
            `File is referenced from :\n ${storageReference}:\n\n Image URL is:\n ${url}`,
          );
          console.log(`url is available here ${url}`);
           //after this point URL is no longer available
        });
      });

      if (result.nextPageToken) {
        return listFilesAndDirectories(reference, result.nextPageToken);
      }

      return Promise.resolve();
    });
  }

  const storageReference = firebase
    .storage()
    .refFromURL('gs://app404.com/images');

  listFilesAndDirectories(storageReference).then(() => {
    console.log('Started listing image download urls');
  });

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={SharedStyles.header}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
            }}>
            <Hamburg />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Header title="Gallery" />
        </View>
        <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <View>
                <Text>
                  Welcome to the Abulad Gallery! Come back for more content....
                </Text>
                <Image
                  source={{
                    uri: {url}//url is not defined
                  }}
                  style={styles.fetchedImage}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

a way to preserve the state even outside the function is needed so image can be displayed.
Thanks

Comment: You might have noticed the error message telling you that react does not export anything named `setState`

Comment: i didn't notice such error, the only  error in get is when trying to access URL outside the function. every other thing looks fine

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use hooks without really using them correctly. `useState` is an initialisation function in React, it essentially creates an initial state and creates a reference in React execution stack, that when the returned `set*` function is called, the node should re-render.

This is how you use `useState`:

```
import { useState} from "react";

const Gallery: () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [ downloadUrl, setDownloadUrl ] = useState({ url: undefined });
  console.log(downloadUrl);
  // should be {url: undefined} on 1st render, {url: <some url>} on subsequent renders

  // This should be refactored to `useEffect` to take advantage of async operations in React
  function listFilesAndDirectories(reference, pageToken) {
    return reference.list({pageToken}).then(result => {
      result.items.forEach(ref => {
        // call getDownloadURL on every object reference
        ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          // An array would be better here, but this is just for example
          setDownloadUrl({ url }); // creates obj {url: url}, will cause a re-render once execution is complete
          console.log(
            `File is referenced from :\n ${storageReference}:\n\n Image URL is:\n ${url}`,
          );
          console.log(`url is available here ${url}`);
           //after this point URL is no longer available
        });
      });

      if (result.nextPageToken) {
        return listFilesAndDirectories(reference, result.nextPageToken);
      }

      return Promise.resolve();
    });
  }

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={SharedStyles.header}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
            }}>
            <Hamburg />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Header title="Gallery" />
        </View>
        <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <View>
                <Text>
                  Welcome to the Abulad Gallery! Come back for more content....
                </Text>
                <Image
                  source={{
                    uri: { downloadUrl.url }//url is not defined
                  }}
                  style={styles.fetchedImage}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
}
```

Once you've got that working, you can update the image placeholder to use a spinner icon, or some other loading icon eg.

```
{ !downloadUrl.url ? <Spinner /> : (
  <div>...</div>
)}
```

Comment: Url is still not accessible from outside the funcrion